# Digital Frame with RaspberryPi zero

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, fbi

I'm building a Digital Frame with a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

To do that, I bought a LCD Panel and I connected it to my Raspberry Pi Zero W.
I use Raspbian Lite because I don't want to use all Pi Zero Resources.

The photos are stored into a NAS and the Pi Zero at the boot mounts the photos folder.

To show the photos on the display I used the command line tool: "FBI"

This is the script to show the photos:

```
#!/bin/bash
# slideshow script for raspberry pi
# this file is for autolaunching your slideshow program fbi at startup
#
INTERVAL=5 #how many seconds for each slide
#fbi -noverbose -a -t $INTERVAL /home/pi/slides/*.jpg

# here's almost exactly the same, but with photos appearing in random order
# comment the above fbi line and uncomment this one to use it
fbi -noverbose -a -t $INTERVAL -u /mnt/fotografie/SlideShow/*.jpg
#
# NEW alternate method using feh (thanks TechnologyClassroom for suggestion)
# feh -FZYD 5 --cycle-once /home/pi/slides/*.png
```

I'm wondering if there is a command line software to show the photos or which is the best way to use FBI.

Thank you and best regards,
Federico

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. "is [there] a command line software to show the photos": `fbi` and `feh`. The best way depends on what you want; the script already shows different ways.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/feh

Comment: @LjmDullaart I mean which is the best to work with Raspbian Lite and with a WiFi connection. Also if you know where I can find some examples or project.